# Recursive jQuery selection

Tags: jquery

I have `divs` in the following format

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="button">B</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="button">B</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="button">B</div>
</div>
```

I want to display each `.button` when their `.box` parent is hovered. How?

Comment: Please explain why this must be done with jQuery when CSS is designed for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.box {width: 30px; height:30px; margin:5px; display: block; float:left; cursor:default; font-size: 24px; font-weight:bold; padding: 5px; border: 1px #009 solid; background-color:#DFCCF4; text-align:center;}
.button {display: none;}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.box').mouseover(function(){
        $('.button',this).show();
    });
    $('.box').mouseout(function(){
        $('.button',this).hide();
    }); 
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
  <div class="button">B</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="button">B</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="button">B</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This section is what you need - though I have posted the full example.
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.box').mouseover(function(){
        $('.button',this).show();
    });
    $('.box').mouseout(function(){
        $('.button',this).hide();
    }); 
});

</script>

Comment: You can also use .hover() instead of mouseover and mouseout. hover() takes 2 functions, the first one is called on mouse in, the second on mouse out. It's a bit cleaner but it does exactly the same as the above.

Answer (score 5):

Just use CSS:

```
.box:hover .button {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: And of course, above that we need `.box .button { display: none; }`

Comment: Just answer what I asked. Stay in limits. Didn't you see "JQuery"?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS:

```
.button { display: none; }
.box:hover > .button { display: block; }
```

Comment: Just answer what I asked. Stay in limits. Didn't you see "JQuery"?

Comment: It's inappropriate to set limits on SO without explaining them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't use the `:hover` CSS psuedo selector (because it doesn't work on non anchor elements in IE6 for example) then the following will work:

CSS

```
.box .button { display: none; }
```

jQuery

```
$(".box").hover(
    function() {
        $(".button", this).show();
    },
    function() {
        $(".button", this).hide();
    }
)
```